# Custom (value) type in azure function http trigger as route param

Tags: .net, azure-functions, domain-driven-design

In DDD it is common to define you own value types, e.g. for a UserId. Now I want to bind to the value type directly in an azure function http trigger. The parameter is part of the route.

If a define the parameter as Guid this works fine.

```
[FunctionName("getUserSettings")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserSettings(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",
        Route = "user-settings/{userId:guid}")]
    HttpRequest req,
    Guid userId)
{
    ...
}
```

But now I want to use my value type, which yields the exception `System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'UserId'.`

Is there any way to register some custom converter for my type?

```
[FunctionName("getUserSettings")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserSettings(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",
        Route = "user-settings/{userId:guid}")]
    HttpRequest req,
    UserId userId)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to imagine that your value objects are part of the model you've come up with to solve one or more problems in a particular domain. At the boundaries though, one is usually dealing with primitives, so it makes sense to map those primitives onto your value objects. A model could very well be hosted via a plethora of mechanisms / protocols / hosts / etc. Just write the `new UserId(userId)` and be done with it.